# sed trying to change hostnames in log files but - (dash, minus) causing issues

Tags: regex, search, sed, replace

I am new to sed and need to change hundred of hostnames in a number of large log files

for example

```
URL:http://test-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>
```

I need to change this to

```
URL:http[s]://hostname.compute-1234.cloud.internal: .Response code: 503>
```

I have tried using sed regex

```
s'/http[s]\?:\/\/[^ ]./http[s]:\/\/hostname/'
```

but as the dash in the host is being treated as a word it returns

```
URL:http[s]://hostname-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>
```

so need a little help to understand where I am going wrong

Thanks
in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use

```
sed 's~\(https\{0,1\}://\)[^.]\{1,\}~\1hostname~'  # POSIX BRE
sed -E 's~(https?://)[^.]+~\1hostname~'            # POSIX ERE
```

See [an online demo](https://ideone.com/Y5AIFh):

```
s='URL:http://test-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503> '
sed 's~\(https\{0,1\}://\)[^.]\{1,\}~\1hostname~' <<< "$s"
# => URL:http://hostname.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>
```

**Details**

- `\(https\{0,1\}://\)` - Group 1 (referred to with `\1` in the replacement part): `http` or `https` and then `://` string
- `[^.]\{1,\}` - 1 or more chars other than `.`
- `\1hostname` - (RHS): Group 1 value and `hostname` substring.

Answer (score 1):

Use a different delimiter (it does not need to be `/`) so that you don't need to escape lots of slashes. I'll use `|` as delimiter, and this regex will do:

```
sed 's|http[s]\?://[^.]*|http[s]://hostname|'
```

The `http[s]\?://[^.]*` gets the string between `http://` or `https://` and the next dot character (in your case, that is `http://test-wls-1`) and transforms it into `http[s]://hostname`, yielding:

```
$ echo 'URL:http://test-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>' |
    sed 's|http[s]\?://[^.]*|http[s]://hostname|'
URL:http[s]://hostname.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>
```

---

Your original attempt `http[s]\?:\/\/[^ ].` matches `http://` or `https://` followed by any non-space character (`[^ ]`) and any other character (`.`). So the output would be

```
$ echo 'URL:http://test-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>' |
    sed 's/http[s]\?:\/\/[^ ]./http[s]:\/\/hostname/'
URL:http[s]://hostnamest-wls-1.compute-1234.cloud.internal .Response code: 503>
```

See that `te` in `test-...` is missing in the output.

Comment: Many thanks Quasímodo 's|http[s]\?://[^.]*|http[s]://hostname|' worked a treat